# Python, pyrogram - вылет при попытке входа в аккаунт

Tags: python, python-3.x, сессия, pyrogram

Код следующий:

```
from pyrogram import Client
from pyrogram.errors import FloodWait, BadRequest
from time import sleep
import tgcrypto
from colorama import init, Fore, Back, Style
import dbm

def dbm_base():
    file = dbm.open( 'api.dbm' ,'c')
    try:
        file['api_id']
    except:
        file['api_id'] = input('Введите api_id:')
        file['api_hash'] = input('Введите api_hash:')
    file.close()
    return dbm.open( 'api.dbm' ,'r')
file = dbm_base()
api_id = int(file['api_id'].decode())
api_hash = file['api_hash'].decode()

dbm_base()

session = 1

while True:
    with Client(f"{session}", api_id, api_hash, workdir="sessions") as app:
        with open('links.txt', "r") as links:
            for link in links:
                try:
                    app.join_chat(f"{link}")
                    print(Fore.GREEN + f'Аккаунт присоединился по ссылке {link}')
                    sleep(10)
                except FloodWait as e:
                    print(Fore.RED + f'Аккаунт словил флуд, сплю {e.x} секунд')
                    sleep(e.x)
                    app.join_chat(f"{link}")
                    print(Fore.GREEN + f'Аккаунт присоединился по ссылке {link}')
                    sleep(10)
                except BadRequest as err:
                    print(Fore.RED + f'Неверная ссылка\n')
                except Exception as error:
                    print(Fore.RED + f"Unexpected ERROR: {error}\n")
        session += 1
```

Ошибка следующая:

[image: ERROR]

Я понял, что нельзя при старте сессии клиента открывать папку и искать там, тогда вопрос: как мне войти в папку sessions и там искать сессии?

P.S. Это именно вылет, т.к. дальше аккаунт должен начать входить в чаты и каналы по ссылкам и та часть кода 100% рабочая

Comment: Почему вы решили, что это именно вылет, а не успешное завершение работы?

Comment: «дальше аккаунт должен начать входить в чаты» — почему вы решили что должен?

Comment: Ну а вообще, если я правильно понимаю код pyrogram, официальный способ указать папку — использовать параметр workdir, примерно так `Client(session, api_id, api_hash, workdir="sessions")`

Comment: «Обновил pyrogram» — а свой код под изменения новой версии не забыли обновить? И уберите этот вредный try-except, он прячет за собой подробную информацию об ошибке

Comment: Ну а всё-таки какая версия pyrogram у вас была **перед** обновлением? Наверное, всё-таки не стоило обновляться до новой мажорной версии не глядя и не разобравшись, к каким последствиям это приведёт

Comment: В общем, по симптомам я предполагаю, что у вас стояло очень-очень древнее (0.x?), которое использовало json-сессии, в версиях 1.x формат сессий изменили на sqlite3 и для переходного периода сделали автоматическую миграцию из json, а в версии 2.0 миграцию убрали. И теперь sqlite3 ругается, что старые json-сессии не являются совместимым форматом. Нужно было выполнять плавное поэтапное обновление через несколько промежуточных версий pyrogram, чтобы сессии правильно сконвертировались в новый формат